# Unable to connect Websocket with wss using SSL Certificate

Tags: django, linux, nginx, websocket, lets-encrypt

I have added SSL certificate from letsencrypt and did configuration using Nginx but unable to connect to the websocket using WSS. It works fine if change the configuration to ws.

Here is the configuration file

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Begin by testing if your websocket server works with the [PieSocket websocket tester](https://www.piesocket.com/websocket-tester), you can use their chrome extension to test the ws version.

Then edit your nginx configuration and try following, it works for me:

```
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default Upgrade;
    '' close;
}

location / {
            proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
            proxy_send_timeout 86400s;
            keepalive_timeout 86400s;
            # prevents 502 bad gateway error
            proxy_buffers 8 32k;
            proxy_buffer_size 64k;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            reset_timedout_connection on;
        }
```

You may replace `/` with `/ws/` but I highly recommend using a dedicated subdomain for your websocket server instead of path, for scaling purposes in the future.

Comment: Actually I have done same configuration before and it worked for me but then i created a snapshot of server at amazon lightsail to increase ram and now its not working for me.

Comment: Did you try the solution above? also, recheck your server without wss (with ws), you can use the tool I linked in the answer.

Comment: fixed actually it was my bad , i didn't allow port in AWS and nothing was wrong in configuration. Thanks